# How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to be able to define an attribute with a prefix in a xml element.

For instance...

```
<nc:Person s:id="ID_Person_01"></nc:Person>
```

In order to do this I though that the following would have worked.

```
XmlElement TempElement = XmlDocToRef.CreateElement("nc:Person", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
TempElement.SetAttribute("s:id", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0", "ID_Person_01");
```

Unfortunately, XmlElement.SetAttribute(string, string, string) does not seem to support parsing the prefix as I receive the error below.

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

How would I define an attribute with prefix?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you've already declared your namespace in the root node, you just need to change the `SetAttribute` call to use the unprefixed attribute name. So if your root node defines a namespace like this:

```
<People xmlns:s='http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0'>
```

You can do this and the attribute will pick up the prefix you've already established:

```
// no prefix on the first argument - it will be rendered as
// s:id='ID_Person_01'
TempElement.SetAttribute("id", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0", "ID_Person_01");
```

If you have not yet declared the namespace (and its prefix), the three-string [`XmlDocument.CreateAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2zzesf.aspx) overload will do it for you:

```
// Adds the declaration to your root node
var attribute = xmlDocToRef.CreateAttribute("s", "id", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0");
attribute.InnerText = "ID_Person_01"
TempElement.SetAttributeNode(attribute);
```

Comment: This worked. I already had the namespace in the root node. Just had to remove the prefix from the first argument of SetAttribute method. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful. One small thing - there is an equals/assignment operator missing `XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDocToRef.`

Answer (score 2):

The [XMLDocument.CreateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createattribute.aspx) method can take 3 strings: specified Prefix, LocalName, and NamespaceURI.  You could then add the attribute to the element.  Something like this might work for you:

```
XmlAttribute newAttribute = XmlDocToRef.CreateAttribute("s", "id", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0");
TempElement.Attributes.Append(newAttribute):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the attribute directly and adding it to the element:

```
XmlAttribute attr = XmlDocToRef.CreateAttribute("s", "id", "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0");
attr.InnerText = "ID_Person_01";
TempElement.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my search kept taking me here, I'll answer this for `XElement`.  I don't know if this solution is also valid for `XmlElement`, but it will hopefully at least help others using `XElement`, who end up here.

Based on [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1655370.aspx/1?System%20Xml%20XmlException%20The%20character%20hexadecimal%20value%200x3A%20cannot%20be%20included%20in%20a%20name%20) I added `xml:space="preserve"` to all data-nodes in some template, before looking up and adding their contents. It's weird code IMO (I would prefer three parameters as shown above, but it does the job:

```
 foreach (XElement lElement in root.Descendants(myTag))
 {
      lElement.Add(new XAttribute(root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xml") + "space", "preserve"));
 }
```