# How to modify DocumentElement.Prefix in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have some sets of xml in which I have to add namespace prefix on nodes which doesn't have any prefix.

I have written a code which works for all nodes other than root element.

Please point me to the thing which I can do change the root element prefix as well.

```
 private void ReplaceFile(string xmlfile)
 {
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(xmlfile);
     var a = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:mailxml12tm");
     a.Value = "http://idealliance.org/Specs/mailxml12.0a/mailxml_tm";
     doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(a);
     doc.DocumentElement.Prefix = "mailxml12tm";
     //foreach (XmlNode item in doc.SelectNodes("//*").Cast<XmlNode>().Where(item => item.Prefix.Length == 0))
     //{
     //    item.Prefix = "mailxml12tm";
     //}
     doc.Save(xmlfile);
}
```

The xml file:

```
<DeliveryApptCreateRequest 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    p3:ApptType="Pallet" p3:PickupOrDelivery="Delivery" 
    p3:ShipperApptRequestID="4490B0C07355" p3:SchedulerCRID="6498874" 
    xmlns:p3="http://idealliance.org/Specs/mailxml12.0a/mailxml_defs">
    <SubmitterTrackingID xmlns="http://idealliance.org/Specs/mailxml12.0a/mailxml_tm">2CAD3FBC71B1E1517021</SubmitterTrackingID>
    <DestinationEntry xmlns="http://idealliance.org/Specs/mailxml12.0a/mailxml_tm">No</DestinationEntry>
    <OneTimeAppt xmlns="http://idealliance.org/Specs/mailxml12.0a/mailxml_tm">
        <PreferredAppt>2012-07-01T09:00:00Z</PreferredAppt>
    </OneTimeAppt> 
</DeliveryApptCreateRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255337/219344
by [Jeff Sternal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47886/jeff-sternal)?

> If you've already declared your namespace in the root node, you just
>   need to change the SetAttribute call to use the unprefixed attribute
>   name. So if your root node defines a namespace like this:
>
> `<People xmlns:s='http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0'>`
>
> You can do this and the attribute will pick up the prefix you've
>   already established:
>
> `// no prefix on the first argument - it will be rendered as //`
>   `s:id='ID_Person_01' TempElement.SetAttribute("id",`
>   `"http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0", "ID_Person_01");`
>
> If you have not yet declared the namespace (and its prefix), the
>   three-string XmlDocument.CreateAttribute overload will do it for you:
>
> `// Adds the declaration to your root node var attribute =`
>   `xmlDocToRef.CreateAttribute("s", "id",`
>   `"http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0"); attribute.InnerText =`
>   `"ID_Person_01" TempElement.SetAttributeNode(attribute);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<test xmlns='123'/>");
XmlElement e = doc.DocumentElement;       
e.Prefix = "a";
Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
```

Output:

```
<a:test xmlns="123" xmlns:a="123" />
```

Founded in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecf3e2k0%28v=vs.110%29).

**Edit:**

Since it does not work with your main element you can use `.Replace("<", "<Prefixe:"));` on your root element as a `String`. It's not pretty but it does the job.

Comment: But when you save the the doc it will remain same as test instead of a:test

Comment: Please check my xml file.It is not working with it i think due to some namespaceuri problem or else