# C# XML 'colon' in root name possible?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating a simple XMl file, and the root name must be 'site:Root', so I do the following:

```
    private XmlDocument CreateXMLDocument()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlDeclaration xmlDec = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null);
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDec);

        XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("site:Root");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlRoot);

        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

However the outerXml property only shows 'Root' for the root name. How can I have the root name to be 'site:Root'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"site:"` bit with the colon in is actually your XML Namespace, set this property instead. Look at this question: [How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix)

Comment: The root node must look like this: <site:root xmlns:site="urn:myurl">