# How to add XML attribute in XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am generating XML file from C# code but when I add attribute to XML node I am getting problem. Following is code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docRoot = doc.CreateElement("eConnect");
doc.AppendChild(docRoot);
XmlNode eConnectProcessInfo = doc.CreateElement("eConnectProcessInfo");
XmlAttribute xsiNil = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi:nil");
xsiNil.Value = "true";
eConnectProcessInfo.Attributes.Append(xsiNil);
docRoot.AppendChild(eConnectProcessInfo);
```

Result:

```
<eConnect>
    <eConnectProcessInfo nil="true"/>
</eConnect>
```

Expected Result:

```
<eConnect>
    <eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true"/>
</eConnect>
```

XML attribute is not adding "xsi:nil" in xml file.
Please help me for this, where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix

Comment: Just a hint: this is a lot easier with XLinq (`XElement`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the schema to your document for xsi first

**UPDATE you also need to add the namespace as an attribute to the root object**

```
//Store the namespaces to save retyping it.
string xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
string xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
schema.Namespaces.Add("xsi", xsi);
schema.Namespaces.Add("xsd", xsd);
doc.Schemas.Add(schema);
XmlElement docRoot = doc.CreateElement("eConnect");
docRoot.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi",xsi);
docRoot.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd",xsd);
doc.AppendChild(docRoot);
XmlNode eConnectProcessInfo = doc.CreateElement("eConnectProcessInfo");
XmlAttribute xsiNil = doc.CreateAttribute("nil",xsi);
xsiNil.Value = "true";
eConnectProcessInfo.Attributes.Append(xsiNil);
docRoot.AppendChild(eConnectProcessInfo);
```

Comment: This is not giving result: My expected result is :::                                                  <eConnect xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOPTransactionType>
    <eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taUpdateCreateItemRcd xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </SOPTransactionType>
</eConnect>

Comment: @user2493287 Please see updated answer, I forgot to include the line that adds the xmlns attribute.  I'm also slapping in the xsd namespace you want

Comment: @user2493287 My answer doesn't include it, but your comment indicates that you need to create the `SOPTransactionType>` element before you add the `eConnectProcessInfo`

Answer (score 2):

Below is the simplest way to append an `xsi:nil="true"` element:

```
XmlNode element = null;
XmlAttribute xsinil = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xsinil.Value = "true";
element.Attributes.Append(xsinil);
```