# Unable to add "xsi:schemaLocation" in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Using following code:

```
if (requestXml.DocumentElement != null)
{
    requestXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.abcde.com/qazxw azszz.xsd");
    requestXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.abcde.com/qazxw");
    requestXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
}
```

And getting following XML:

```
<qazxw schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/qazxw azszz.xsd" xmlns="http://www.abcde.com/qazxw" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

C# removes

> "xsi:"

from schemaLocation, want it like this

> "xsi:schemaLocation"

. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix)