# XML why colon is missing in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to generate a xml code like below example

```
<Styles>
   <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal" />
</Styles>
```

My C# code is

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement Styles = doc.CreateElement("Styles");
doc.AppendChild(Styles);

XmlElement Style = doc.CreateElement("Style");
Style.SetAttribute("ss:ID", "Default");
Style.SetAttribute("ss:Name", "Normal");
Styles.AppendChild(Style);
```

why 'ss:' is missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix)

Comment: This is a namespace prefix

Comment: XmlDocument is an obsolete class. Use Linq to Xml instead. See [How to create a document with namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml)