# missing xsi in noNamespaceSchemaLocation for xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

below is the format I wanted to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
```

and here is the code I have so far which is the xsi is missing

```
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",null,null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);
            XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("eExact");
            doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

            XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
            element.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            element.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "eExact-Schema.xsd");
```

Below is the xml result I have from this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
```

Thank you so much in advance for the help.

Comment: Use `element.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "eExact-Schema.xsd");` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255337/3744182) to [How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255311/3744182).  Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNaqcg

Answer (score 0):

you can add the namespace in the call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlElement_SetAttribute_System_String_System_String_System_String_