# XmlElement.SetAttribute removes "xsi:" prefix. How can I keep it?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

When adding the attribute `xsi:nil="true"` to an XML element in C# (.NET 5), it loses the prefix. Why does that happen, and more importantly, how can I make sure the prefix is added after all? I need it in order for the XML to pass an XSD.

Example. Consider the following code:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

var foo = document.CreateElement("foo");
document.AppendChild(foo);
foo.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

var bar = document.CreateElement("bar");
bar.SetAttribute("xsi:nil", "true");
foo.AppendChild(bar);

using var stream = new MemoryStream();
using var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Indent = true });
document.Save(xmlWriter);
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

This results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <bar nil="true" />
</foo>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create XmlElement attributes with prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255311/how-to-create-xmlelement-attributes-with-prefix)

Comment: Realise that no prefix is specially blessed or given meaning without being introduced in the document via a namespace declaration. `xsi:` doesn't mean anything in and of itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for mentioning that. I don't know if that matter though, but I changed the example to include the namespace for `xsi:`.

Comment: Following the link I gave you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZOZ9Ts

Comment: You're right. Thank you, @canton7! My question is a bit of a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The same namespace defined for the `xsi` prefix needs to be included in the attribute:

```
var bar = document.CreateElement("bar");
var attribute = document.CreateAttribute("xsi", "nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
attribute.InnerText = "true";
bar.SetAttributeNode(attribute);
foo.AppendChild(bar);
```